# git with permission denied when gitlab job run

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have gitlab as a ci/cd tool and I'm trying to run tests, however when the job run, I'm getting a permission issue with git

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/uesdfse/0/testing/repo/.git/
rm: cannot remove '.git/hooks/post-checkout': Permission denied
```

this is what the job does:

```
  script:
    - docker-compose run node-setup npm run build
    - chown -R ${CURRENT_UID} node_modules/
    # - npm run build
```

this is what its previous jobs does (which is executed successfully):

```
docker-compose run node-setup npm install
```

does anyone have any idea what can be causing this issue? and does anyone knows a workaround to fix it?